# Retrieve the "kind" of a Class and Class Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, instance

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to check if a object is a class or a class instance. For example if I have

```
Article  # It is a class name
@article # It is an instance of the Article class
```

maybe I may do something like the following:

```
kind?(Article)  # => class
kind?(@article) # => class_instance
```

**How can I retrieve that information?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html) has a method called `class`:

```
@article.class # => Article
```

There's also `kind_of?`:

```
if @article.kind_of? Class
   # class type
elsif @article.kind_of? Article
   # other type
end
```

Comment: I don't want to retrieve the class name or something of similar. I want to check if a object is a class itself or it is a class instance.

Comment: I prefer to use `is_a?` instead of `kind_of?`, but that is just personal taste.

Comment: @Backo, Can you explain what you meant by _I want to check if a object is a class itself or it is a class instance_?

Comment: leenasn - "I mean" a object is a class when it is stated as 'class Article ... end' and you use the 'Article' (*not* the String "Article" but something like "Article".constantize # => Article); "I mean" a object is a class instance when you initialize an instance of a class (for example @article = Article.new # => #<Article id:1, ...> - '@article' is the class instance).

Answer (score 1):

Class is an object of class `Class`:

```
class A
end

Class === A       #=> true
Class === A.new   #=> false
A === A.new       #=> true
```

`A.new` here is an object of class `A`